# Promise not resolved after a validation failure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, deferred

I have a login form which is created through the promise object.
Everything works fine except a case when the forma validation comes into action.
Here is my html file.

```
   <form id="signin" class="signinform" autocomplete="off"> 
   <span ng-show="errorName" class="error_block">{{ errorName }}</span>
   <input placeholder="User Name" ng-model="user.name" type="text" name="user_name" required>
   <input placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" type="password" name="password" required>
  <input type="submit" ng-click="submit(user)" value="Log IN" id="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the controller where the ng-click is written

```
  $scope.submit =  function(user){
   LoginService.login(user)
    .then(function(response) {           
         var userInfo = response.userName
         $rootScope.$emit('myEvent',userInfo);
         $location.path("/details/1");
    },
    function(error) {
      $scope.errorName = "Invalid Username or Password";
    });
 }
```

Here is the factory service for

```
app.factory("LoginService", function($http, $q, $window) {
var userInfo;
var deferred = $q.defer();
 function login(user) {
  $http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: "login.php",
   data: { "userName": user.name, "password": user.password },
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'}
   }).then(function(result) { 
   userInfo = {
    accessToken: result.data.login.token,
    userName: result.data.login.name
   };
   $window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = JSON.stringify(userInfo);  
    deferred.resolve(userInfo);
    }, function(error) {
    deferred.reject(error);
   });      
   return deferred.promise;
   }

   return {
    login: login
   };
 });
```

Now what happens is when i visit the form first time and submit the form with valid results the login process is successful and i am redirected to 'details'.But if the username or password goes wrong and the form is rejected the error shows up.

And then after that if i enter the correct credentials and hit submit i am not redirected to 'details' and stuck on the same login form with that error still showing Up. 
But When i refresh the page i am already logged In. Thats because the http request has occurred and userInfo has been set.

I debugged the code and found that the then function is not being executed in my $scope.submit and that may be because the promise has not been resolved. I had tried several scope.apply and other stuff but nothing worked.
Could anyone help whats happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Akis said, you create a deferred only once, so once it's fulfilled (or rejected) once, that's it, forever for that promise. This is because a promise can be "resolved" only once (either fulfilled or rejected)

> P.S. pet hate ... the language of promises - resolved promise means fulfilled or rejected - but most examples use the name `resolve` to fulfil!!

I've added this answer because you don't need to use deferred at all, seeing as $http clearly returns a promise - using deferred (or `new Promise` constructor) in this instance is considered an anti-pattern

Note also, that I added `$window.sessionStorage.removeItem("userInfo");` just before `$http` is executed - seems logical to clear the sessionInfo at this point

```
app.factory("LoginService", function($http, $q, $window) {
    function login(user) {
        // added this as it seems it should be done!
        $window.sessionStorage.removeItem("userInfo");
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "login.php",
            data: {
                "userName": user.name,
                "password": user.password
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
            }
        }).then(function(result) {
            var userInfo = {
                accessToken: result.data.login.token,
                userName: result.data.login.name
            };
            $window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = JSON.stringify(userInfo);
            return userInfo;
        });
    }
    return {
        login: login
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the promise has already been resolved.

Try to move your `var deferred = $q.defer();` declaration in the `login` function.

```
function login(user) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: "login.php",
   data: { "userName": user.name, "password": user.password },
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'}
   }).then(function(result) { 
   userInfo = {
    accessToken: result.data.login.token,
    userName: result.data.login.name
   };
   $window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = JSON.stringify(userInfo);  
    deferred.resolve(userInfo);
    }, function(error) {
    deferred.reject(error);
   });      
   return deferred.promise;
   }

   return {
    login: login
   };
```

Comment: Thanx @akis , that worked. Honestly speaking i was on a major confusing about the promise concept . But that cleared a lot. There was no need of a negative score.i am new to Angular and stack overflow.:(

Comment: @ronit btw it wasnt me that downvoted :D your question was just fine